# Load page depending on what the value of ?id=something in the url

Tags: php

So I want to load for example:

```
<center>
    <h3>What comes after 6?</h3>

    <form action="">
        <select name="answerone">
            <option value="0">Please select a number</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
        </select>
        <h3>What comes after 2?</h3>
        <select name="answertwo">
            <option value="0">Please select a number</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
        </select>
        <h3>What comes after 7?</h3>
        <select name="answertwo">
            <option value="0">Please select a number</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</center>
```

if the url is http://eduhub.dk/en/math/Counting/assignment?id=1
but if it's http://eduhub.dk/en/math/Counting/assignment?id=2 I want it to disappear, how would I do that? I've tried a lot of things, but it won't work, and this was the last thing I wanted to do, because I don't want to look helpless... But in this case I am helpless.

Comment: Hint: the value of `id` can be read in PHP from `$_GET['id']` in the URLs you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the id by `$_GET['id']`. Using that you can either use `require_once` to include that file into your page or if you store your data in the database, you can make a query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the whole thing to disappear, then kill it

```
<?php
if ($_GET['id'] == 2) die();
```